# ¿Cómo devuelvo solo los números enteros de una función con números y strings?

Tags: javascript

```
function soloNumeros(array) {
```

La funcion llamada 'soloNumeros' recibe como argumento un arreglo de enteros y strings llamado 'array'.
Debe devolver un arreglo con solo los enteros. Ej:

```
soloNumeros([1, 'Henry', 2]) debe retornar [1, 2]
```

Tu código acá:

¿Cómo debería plantear el código?

Comment: Bienvenido @Aeg97. Deberías plantearlo comparando los objetos del arreglo  con un comparador `.isInteger` si solo te interesan números enteros o `typeof value === 'number'` si no se limita a enteros.

Comment: Te recomiendo incluir un [mcve] y enfocar tus dudas con respecto al código que ya hayas realizado, ya que el tipo de preguntas que demuestran poco esfuerzo terminan cerradas.

Answer (score 0):

checa sus tipos de dato

```
var a = [1, 'Henry', 2]
function soloNumeros(array){
 var tmp_array = [];
 array.map( val => {
 if(typeof(val) == "number")
  tmp_array.push(val)
 })
 return tmp_array
}
```

output

```
soloNumeros(a) //[1, 2]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Emma

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la siguiente funcion

```js
    function soloNumeros(array)  { 
      return array.filter(item => typeof item === 'number') 
    }
```

o tambien puedes utilizar Number.isInteger para verificar que no tenga decimales

```js
    function soloNumeros(array)  { 
      return array.filter(item => Number.isInteger(item)) 
    }
```